# Update old data and add new data using tableadapter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, insert-update

My code should update old records and at the same time if the a new record is found it should likewise insert it in the DB... I am using table adpater in doing this method.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim pta As New PHDSTableAdapters.productdatabaseTableAdapter
    pta.Updateproduct(TextBox1.Text, ComboBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
    pta.Fill(myds.productdatabase)
    Dim lta As New PHDSTableAdapters.lotnoTableAdapter
    Dim lt = lta.GetDataBylotno(TextBox5.Text)
    Dim l As phaccess.PHDS.lotnoRow = lt.Rows(0)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DGV.Rows.Count - 1

        For Each l In myds.lotno
            Dim lot As String = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            Dim del As Date = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            Dim exp As Date = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            Dim quantity As Integer = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            Dim sup = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
            Dim disc = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value

            If l.productid = TextBox5.Text Then
                Dim lotnumber As String = l.lotnumber
                If l.lotnumber <> lot Then
                'the error occurs in the insert statement as it would create duplicates 'of the index...the index of the table is the lot number 
                    lta.Insert(TextBox5.Text, lot, del, exp, quantity, sup, disc) 
                Else
                    lta.Updateedit(del, exp, quantity, sup, disc, lot)
                    lta.Fill(myds.lotno)
                End If
            End If
            If lot = "" Then
                closeform()
                lta.Fill(myds.lotno)
                Button3.Enabled = False
                Button1.Visible = True
                Button3.Visible = False
                Button1.Enabled = False
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you need anything else to help me solve this please do ask.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use "DataTable" to upadate DataGridView in your table

For displaying data:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
    sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "table_name")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("table_name")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sTable
```

for updating:

```
sAdapter.Update(sTable)
```

i hope this helps